# How to intercept Skia draw commands from Chromium Browser

Tags: browser, chromium, webassembly, skia, canvaskit

This is an experimental project of mine related to remote browser isolation. I'm trying to intercept [Skia](https://skia.org/) draw commands in a running Chromium instance and later replay them in a different browser instance at client-side via [CanvasKit](https://skia.org/user/modules/canvaskit), a WebAssembly build of Skia.

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out where and how to intercept those draw commands within Chromium source code. Any advice on how to approach my problem is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In Chromium, all the draw operations will be recorded in a `DisplayItemList` which you can find in the definition of class `GraphicsContext` in blink module. Second, these recorded operations will be replayed later when the `CC` thinks it will be right time.

On blink's end, all the things above related code was scattered mostly in `blink/renderer/platform/graphics/graphics_context.cc` and its related files. But if you see all Chromium as a whole, all the graphics things were triggered by `CC (Chrome Compositor)` which maintain a state machine and runs a `draw frame` loops triggered by system's vsync signal in Android. On this loop start, blink ends `draw` recording operations will be pushed. At the end of this loop, the composited frame's image will be translated to a serial of GPU ops and calling the system's GPU devices related APIs to do them. The `CC` related code files can
be found in `components/viz/`. You should read code of class `Display` as a starting key point.

My opinion comes from version `68` and you know code in Chromium changes frequently. So I cannot confirm the files and locations are still correct.