# Get Skia Commands from Chromium DisplayItemList

Tags: rendering, chromium, skia, blink, graphicscontext

Please suggest how can I intercept or extract SKIA commands from a running Chromium instance so that same can be replayed on another browser.
Saw this in another thread asking the same problem
[How to intercept Skia draw commands from Chromium Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293524/how-to-intercept-skia-draw-commands-from-chromium-browser?rq=2)

What confuses me is whether I should be looking at
1)cc or  2)components/viz  or  3)blink

Comment: Maybe the official Blink dev Google group can help you: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please suggest whether I should be looking at cc  or components/viz or blink